# Fragment's view members null on config change, inside ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, zxing

I have an activity with two swipeable fragments inside `ViewPager`.
I have an implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` which handles fragments in `ViewPager`.
The problem is that, I start an Intent(zxing barcode scanner) in fragment A, which calls `onActivityResult()` of parent activity(instead of fragment's, I tried many things but it won't work!).

Anyway, through Activity's `onActivityResult()` I'm fetching the fragment from `ViewPager`, calling a method on it which updates a searchview with scanner result. The fragment is fetched but the searchview which I want to update in Frag A is null(after configuration change, triggered by intent)

Here are my classes, some parts removed for simplicity:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private final String TAG = "21st Polling:";

    static final class TabInfo{
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
        super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = fa;
        mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Acivity which hosts fragments:

```
public class OrderActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        OrderData {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    private Tab cartTab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("A"),
            A.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("B(0)"),
            B.class, null);

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //calling method productScaned() in fragment A here 
        if (scanResult != null) {
             ((A)mTabsAdapter.getItem(0)).productScaned(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        }
    }

}
```

Fragment A:

```
public class A extends SherlockFragment {

    private SearchView svMProducts;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container,
                false);
        svMProducts = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.svMProductsInvoice);
        svMProducts.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);
        svMProducts.requestFocus();

        btnScanBarcode = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnScanBarcode);
        btnScanBarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //tried with IntentIntegrator also, didn't work
                IntentIntegratorSupportV4 integrator = new IntentIntegratorSupportV4(A.this);                         
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void productScaned(String upc){
                //this method gets called but svMProducts view is null!
        svMProducts.setQuery(upc, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

`startActivityForResult(intent, code);` should be called from Fragment in order to receive the result in `Fragment`. The above code does that via `IntentIntegratorSupportV4`, but I also had `onActivityResult()` in `Activity` which was preventing the call on Fragment's `onActivityResult()`